# Twilio call hold not working

Tags: api, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

We are using twilio API for hold call process but we are facing problem :

If we connect the call from A to B, then our call connecting successfully but when we are update the call for hold(Using updating method) then B putting on hold success, but A call disconnecting. 
I want to put B on hold but should not disconnect the A call.

Please give me suitable suggestion for this hold process.

Thanks.

Comment: What would you like A to do while B is on hold?

Comment: I want to A call in-progress but not disconnect because A can retrieve of B after sometime. Need to implement like as simple phone hold process.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly ,Its important to understand that putting a call on hold in the Twilio environment is not a native function rather it works like all updates to a call to connect the call to something else, which could be dialing a number,play an audio, place in queue etc..What you choose to implement the **On Hold** idiom is up to you.

Make sure you are updating the child sid not the parent sid.
 I suggest reading this article [What-is-a-Call-SID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180488-What-is-a-Call-SID-)

If you update the parentsid the child will automatically be lost.
If you update the child sid , the parent call will be disconnected and **continue** with the original twiml that bridged the call in the first place. You have the option of leaving default fallthrough twiml to go to a queue etc..
Another method of implementing hold , is calling out using the[Agent Outbund Conference Api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant#place-a-participant-on-hold)

Comment: We are using child call sid . You are talking about conference call on hold but there is we are using only two call(From A to B call) need to implement for when A will be hold of the B, then B will be put on hold but should not dissconnect the A call.what process we need to implement according to you.